# how do i use the worksheet function.max on a different but active worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to grab "The" max value from column A on a differnt worksheet while a userform initiates.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim newTaskId As Integer
newTaskId = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("baseOfData").Columns("A")) + 1
Me.txtTaskID.Value = newTaskId

End Sub
```

However, this just throws me : Run-Time error '-2147352571 (800200005)
Could not set the value property. Type mismatch..

also tried

```
newTaskId = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("baseOfData").ListObjects(1).ListColumns(1))
```

But then i get unable to get worksheet function

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try removing variable delcaration, because it tries to put some other value than numbers and then inspect what it is :)

Comment: I just tried  MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Worksheets("baseOfData").Columns("A")) 

And the response was the number/int  5  

So youre right it has to be the variable somehow..

Comment: You shouldnt be getting `Could not set the value property. Type mismatch` in the first code. Perhaps and overflow but not `Type Mismatch`. what kind of data do you have in the worksheet?

Comment: I guess the error could be on `Me.txtTaskID.Value = newTaskId`? Do you have any `txtTaskID_Change()` event?

Comment: No change() almost blank workbook,  the table getting the values from is a normal table, with number values only in that colum, i also checked in the worksheet it has been defined as numbers only, it was general.

Comment: May I see your workbook? If yes, can you upload it in a free file sharing site like www.wikisend.com and share the link here. Remember to remove any confidential info if any...

Answer (score 0):

Strange totally unrelated cause of this error.

On the same workbook i had another function, which where not even in the same sub.
but as soon as the userform initiated it cause this error.

I found this out by starting over, and using a new userform, with ONLY this in my original post. and both methods are working now.

Thank you all for the comments and suggestions.